# Manual Transactional Service and DAO layer for JPA with Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, transactions

I am using JPA with Spring. If I were to let Spring handle the transactions, then this is what my Service layer would look like assuming the EntityManager has been properly injected into the DAOs:

```
MyService {

   @Transactional
   public void myMethod() {
       myDaoA.doSomething();
       myDaoB.doSomething();
    }
}
```

However, if I were to do transactions manually, I have to make sure to pass that instance of EntityManager into each of the DAOs within a transaction. Any idea how can this be better refactored? I fee ugly doing new MyDaoA(em) or passing em into each DAO method like doSomething(em).

```
MyService {

   private EntityManagerFactory emf;

   public void myMethod() {
       EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
       EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
       MyDaoA myDaoA = new MyDaoA(em);
       MyDaoB myDaoB = new MyDaoB(em);
       try {
           tx.begin();
           myDaoA.doSomething();
           myDaoB.doSomething();
           tx.commit();
       } catch(Exception e) {
           tx.rollback();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> However, if I were to do transactions
>   manually, I have to make sure to pass
>   that instance of EntityManager into
>   each of the DAOs within a transaction.

This is where you are wrong. From the Spring Reference, [JPA section](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight):

> The main problem with such a DAO is
>   that it always creates a new
>   EntityManager through the factory. **You
>   can avoid this by requesting a
>   transactional EntityManager** (also
>   called "shared EntityManager" because
>   it is a shared, thread-safe proxy for
>   the actual transactional
>   EntityManager) to be injected instead
>   of the factory:

```
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Collection loadProductsByCategory(String category) {
       Query query = em.createQuery(
                        "from Product as p where p.category = :category");
       query.setParameter("category", category);
       return query.getResultList(); 
    }
}
```

> The `@PersistenceContext` annotation has
>   an optional attribute type, which
>   defaults to
>   PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION.
>   This default is what you need to
>   receive **a shared EntityManager proxy**.

Comment: I am still unclear as to how I would go about doing manual transactions with a Service and DAO layer.

Comment: a) I'd probably use TransactionTemplate or JpaTemplate if I had to do it b) don't do it. It's a pain.

Comment: Sorry, this is way beyond the scope of this question. Read the Spring reference, especially the sections Transaction Management http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html and ORM http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html (hint: Exception translation is your friend)

Answer (score 1):

add this to your spring config

```
<bean p:entityManagerFactory-ref="emf" class='org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean' />
```

now you can @Autowired EntityManager inside your dao

for the transaction management, since you already using spring, and @Transactional annotation, i assume you already have one transaction manager declared in your spring.xml

so using spring's transaction management

as

```
transactionStatus = platformTransactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());
// do your work here 
platformTransactionManager.commit(transactionStatus );
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark a bit I guess, but do you know you can do:

[TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.html)

That usually eliminates the majority of cases where you would want/need to use programmatic transactions in a system that otherwise has declarative transactions.